# Combine two columns in one in R without duplication

Tags: r, merge, multiple-columns, mutate

I have a data frame with two columns below:

```
HomeTeam     AwayTeam
Zimbabwe     Kenya
Netherlands  Zimbabwe
Kenya        Amsterdam
```

I want to create a column Team from both these column but it shouldn't repeat the name of the team. How do I go about it?

Comment: Are you looking for `paste(HomeTeam, AwayTeam)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little bit of a guess since your question is not perfectly clear, but I think `union()` is what you're looking for ...

Make up an example:

```r
dd <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
HomeTeam     AwayTeam
Zimbabwe     Kenya
Netherlands  Zimbabwe
Kenya        Amsterdam
")
```

Construct a data frame that contains a single column with the (non-repeated) team names from both columns:

```r
result <- data.frame(Team = with(dd, union(HomeTeam, AwayTeam)))
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply.  This was just an example of what the data looked like.I have a data base called EPL so do I mention "EPL" in 'text ='?

Comment: My data frame is called `dd`; if yours is called `EPL` then substitute that for `dd` in the last line of code shown (the rest is just there to set up an example).

Comment: If this solves your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it (and upvote, if you want)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` option:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), 
               values_to = "Team") %>% 
  distinct(Team)
```

```
  Team       
  <chr>      
1 Zimbabwe   
2 Kenya      
3 Netherlands
4 Amsterdam
```